# MongoDB - MongoImport of JSON (jsonl) - Rename, change types and add fields

Tags: mongodb, performance, mongoimport

i'm new to the topic MongoDB and have 4 different problems importing a big (16GB) file (jsonl) into my MongoDB (simple PSA-Cluster).

Below attached you will find a sample entry from the mentiond JSON-Dump.
With this file which i get from an external provider I actually have 4 problems.

1. **"hotel_id"** is the key and **should** normally be **(re-)named as "_id"**
2. **"hotel_id"** should **not be treated as string** rather than as **Number**
3. **"location"** is **not properly formatted** (if i understood correctly the MongoDB Manual) **as GeoJSON** as it should be like

```
"location": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-93.26838,37.15845]
}
```

instead of

```
"location": {
        "coordinates": {
            "latitude": 37.15845,
            "longitude": -93.26838
        }
    }
```

4. **"dates"** can this be **used to efficiently update** just the records which needs to be updated?

So my challenge is now to transform the data according to my needs before importing the data or at time of import, but in both cases of course as quickly as possible.

Therefore i searched a lot for hints and best practices, but i was not able to find a solution yet, maybe due to the fact that i'm a beginner with MongoDB.

I played around with "jq" to adjust the data and for example add the type which seems to be necessary for the location (point 3), but wasn't really successful.

```
cat dump.jsonl | ./bin/jq --arg typeOfField Point '.location + {type: $typeOfField}'
```

Beside that i was injecting a sample dump of round-about 500MB which took 1,5 mins when importing it the first time (empty database). If i run it in "upsert" mode it will take round-about 12 hours. So i was also wondering what is the best practice to import such a big JSON-dump?

Any help is appreciated!! :-)

Kind regards,
Lumpy

```
{
    "hotel_id": "12345",
    "name": "Test Hotel",
    "address": {
        "line_1": "123 Test St",
        "line_2": "Apt A",
        "city": "Test City",
    },
    "ratings": {
        "property": {
            "rating": "3.5",
            "type": "Star"
        },
        "guest": {
            "count": 48382,
            "average": "3.1"
        }
    },
    "location": {
        "coordinates": {
            "latitude": 22.54845,
            "longitude": -90.11838
        }
    },
    "phone": "555-0153",
    "fax": "555-7249",
    "category": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Hotel"
    },
    "rank": 42,
    "dates": {
        "added": "1998-07-19T05:00:00.000Z",
        "updated": "2018-03-22T07:23:14.000Z"
    },
    "statistics": {
        "11": {
            "id": 11,
            "name": "Total number of rooms - 220",
            "value": "220"
        },
        "12": {
            "id": 12,
            "name": "Number of floors - 7",
            "value": "7"
        }
    },
    "chain": {
        "id": -2,
        "name": "Test Hotels"
    },
    "brand": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Test Brand"
    }
}
```